Maximize Window
I have a simple Python tkinter script which superimposes a black bar over the normal tkinter header (ie the one containing the tk emblem on the left  side and the decorations on the right side). When I run this script it produces a small window with the usual decorations in the header. I then have to click on the Maximize decoration to open it. The screen then changes to one containing the black bar header. I thought it would be a simple enough task to hard code the maximization of that small window. Unfortunately, not. All my efforts have proved unsuccessful. Most maximization efforts have produced either a page with a normal tkinter header and with the rest of the page black or else an all black screen. None replicate the result I get when the maximize decoration is physically clicked. Perhaps this is a window focus problem.
Here is the script:
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.floater = FloatingWindow(self)

class FloatingWindow(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.overrideredirect(True)
        self.attributes( '-topmost', 1)
   
        # Maximize the window
        self.maximise_window("zoomed")
        
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           ", bg = "Black")


        self.label.pack(side="right", fill="both", expand=True)



app=App()
app.mainloop()

Checked online for examples which I tried unsuccessfully

You can maximise the small window, which is actually the root window instead of  the FloatingWindow:
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.floater = FloatingWindow(self)
        self.attributes("-fullscreen", True)

This sets the window to fullscreen.
However, at least on my device, the "decorations" (window control buttons, incl. the window close button) disappear when this is used, so you should give the user a way to exit the program using, e.g., a button that is binded to self.destroy().

Those decorations you're clicking are on the root window, not your floating window. Your new window is positioned at the top left corner. It's just not real noticeable until you maximise the root window. Change the color to blue or red and you could see it easier.
I don't know what maximise_window is supposed to be. Is that a function not shown? You can maximise the new window with self.state('zoomed').
Lastly, you're getting a black screen because the only thing in your new window is a label with a black backgound with fill='both' expand=True so it's filling up the whole window. Try setting side='top' fill='x' and lose the expand and you'll get what I assume you were looking for.
